# Django react render

Tags: django, reactjs

What the best way to create a SPA on react with django?
Differents parts with only rest api or Django render (as a simple template, for example). What profit with to use django render? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We currently have integrated React mini apps into our existing Django project.

We simply return the context which includes the props:

```
class HelloWorld(DetailView):
    template_name = '/path/to/your/template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        props = {
            // your props/data
        }

        context = {
                'component': 'overview.js',
                'title': 'Hello World',
                'props': json.dumps(props)
            }

        return context
```

Then in a template we render our props into the global window scope:

```
<script>
    // Make sure to escape your props to prevent XSS! See here for the source
    // for the json filter: https://gist.github.com/pirate/c18bfe4fd96008ffa0aef25001a2e88f
    window.props = {{props|safe}};
</script>

<script src="/path/to/your/js/{{component}"></script>
```

Then in the React app, I render with the app name and pass in the window.props.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(OverviewApp, window.props), document.getElementById('root');)
```

You can read more about this approach here:

https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a

Comment: You use only one view for all render? Do you use a react-router for routing or you use django for it purpose?

Comment: We currently use Django for routing. But eventually will move towards using React-router and using our REST api rather than Django templating

Comment: I conversely migrate from only react render to Django-react, because I have i differents domains, teams and etc. Clean react does not provide all it functional, I think....

Comment: After some read topics I choose the following scheme: point all - Django. Login page, payment page - route with Django urls. But in main application page - rule with react-router. I use django-webpack-loader and load my bundles (js, css) in home template. And then create request for initial data and any requests for my actions in app